# Set type for variables from form data in Lumen framework.

Tags: lumen

If I send form in Lumen, data can be validated via *validate* method. For example, in some method in some controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'id' => 'required|integer|exists:user',
]);

$user_id = $request->input('id');
```

But variable type of *$user_id* still string. Is there any built in (in framework) methods for getting variable in type which I write? In this case is integer.

I use *intval()* now.

Comment: As far as I know there is no built in way to do this. What you can do, is write middleware or custom request objects that (upon being instantiated and validating) convert the data to the type you want.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge there's no way to define what types input should have in Laravel/Lumen when the value is accessed.

PHP interprets all user input as strings (or arrays of strings).

In `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`, the method that determines if a value is an integer uses `filter_var()` to test if the string value provided by the user conforms to the rules of the `int` type.

Here's what it's actually doing:

```
/**
 * Validate that an attribute is an integer.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return bool
 */
protected function validateInteger($attribute, $value)
{
    if (! $this->hasAttribute($attribute)) {
        return true;
    }

    return is_null($value) || filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false;
}
```

Alas, it does not then update the type of the field it checks, as you have seen.

I think your use of `intval()` is probably the most appropriate option if you absolutely need the value of the `user_id` field to be interpreted as an integer.

Really the only caveat of using `intval()` is that it is limited to returning integers according to your operating system.

From the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

> 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807.

So as long as you keep your user-base to less than 2,147,483,647 users, you shouldn't have any issues with `intval()` if you're on a 32-bit system. Wouldn't we all be so lucky as to have to worry about having *too many* users?

Joking aside, I bring it up because if you're using `intval()` for a user-entered number that might be huge, you run the risk of hitting that cap. Probably not a huge concern though.

And of course, `intval()` will return 0 for non-numeric string input.